# Shared build logic with docker-compose and multi-stage Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am using `docker-compose` with multi-stage Dockerfiles to build and run multiple services. This works, but the "build" portion of each multi-stage build is largely copy-and-pasted between each service's Dockerfile. I want to reduce the copy-and-paste / centralize the common build logic in one spot.

Reading https://engineering.busbud.com/2017/05/21/going-further-docker-multi-stage-builds/ I could create a local image with the shared build steps and have the service Docker files depend on it, but I want the development experience to be a simple `docker-compose up`. Creating a local build image means a developer would have to know to run `docker build [common_build_image]` first so that the build image exists locally and THEN run `docker compose up` to build and run all the services that depend on it.

There doesn't appear to be a way to include a Dockerfile into another Dockerfile. `FROM` does not appear to support local paths.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want? Of course I can use a shell script to tie everything together, but that is basically what multi-stage builds was trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: It's not fully clear for me what part is not fine for you/you don't understand. In docker-compose you can first use the 'build:' to build your helper image and in a later service you can use this helper image in the Dockerfile of a next build or isn't this what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can "compose" `docker-compose`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration which is what I was looking for.